# How do I suppose to resize EFI partition if there is Microsoft Reserved Partition blocking the way?

Tags: partitioning

[image]

How do I suppose to enlarge my EFI partition if I cannot merge Microsoft Reserved Partition with unallocated space?

Comment: You shouldn't have to increase the size.  What problem are you trying to solve?  Simple enough solution, DD the partition then delete it, extend the partition except for 16MB.  then apply the DD image to the 16MB partition.  If this is a critical disk, do more search, on the side effects this might have.

Comment: @Ramhound : What is DD?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=linux+dd&form=EDGTCT&qs=PF&cvid=53c1d111887243b698f7ec2447a99d62&pq=linux+dd